# How can they estimate exoplanet radial velocities using Doppler considering spectrograph resolving power?

Tags: astrophysics, spectroscopy

I read that spectrograph resolving powers, the ratio of wavelength uncertainty to wavelength are like 1000 or 10000. Plugging this into the non relativistic Doppler formula gives a velocity uncertainty like 30000 meters per second. So how can they claim one meter per second accuracy? And what about thermal broadening of spectral lines?

Comment: Of course there's some kind of averaging. They don't need to resolve spectral lines, just detect an overall shift. But it still seems unclear.

Comment: Resolutions above one million can be achieved by professional astronomers. My homemade echelle spectrograph, shown [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/164168/79678) along with several example echellograms, has a resolution, defined as the wavelength divided by FWHM of a spectral ‘line’, of 8500 or a little better.

Comment: One part in a million, times the speed of light, is 300 meters per second, far above the exoplanet velocity precision. The ESPRESSO Very Large Telescope mentions resolving power 100 k

Comment: I updated what I posted at the Sandbox III link, showing the original echellogram (the resolution calculation basis) and an intermediate cropped image. I previously upvoted your question and both answers, but if I can clarify anything, feel free to ask!

Comment: One of the pioneers in using echelle gratings published a number of papers on them, including this one: G.R. Harrison, “The Production of Diffraction Gratings: II. The Design of Echelle Gratings and Spectrographs”, Journal of the Optical Society of America, 39(7), 1949, 522-528. He says theoretical resolving powers can exceed one million, stating a value of 2.5 million at 200 nm. Of course that is theory and as Yogi Berra may have said: “In theory, theory and practice are the same; in practice, they ain’t!” So I will keep looking to see if an actual spectrograph has achieved R = 1 million.

Comment: You may be interested in seeing this: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/49116/45954.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typical resolving powers for exoplanet-finding spectrographs are 50000-100000, but nevertheless, this still means a resolution element has a FWHM of 3-6 km/s. This is to be compared with the radial velocity amplitudes caused by the planets of anywhere from 100 m/s for close-in hot Jupiters, to less than 1 m/s for Earth-like planets.

Measuring the precision of the shift of a spectral line against a wavelength scale boils down to how well you can estimate the centroid of the line. When you estimate the centroid of a Gaussian, the precision of your answer is not limited to the width of the Gaussian. It can, in principle, be of much higher quality. Roughly speaking, the uncertainty in the Gaussian centroid (or mean) is (to a small numerical factor) something like the FWHM divided by the signal-to-noise ratio of the flux in the Gaussian.

In addition, when measuring the spectral lines of stars there is a further $\sqrt{N}$ gain in precision from measuring $N$ spectral lines, since all the lines are shifted by the same velocity. $N$ can be of order 1000 for a sun-like star in a 100 nm spectral range.

The process is entirely analogous to estimating the mean of some distribution by taking repeated measurements. Whilst the estimated width (standard deviation or FWHM) remains approximately constant as the number of measurements increases, the standard error in the mean shrinks by a factor equal to the square root of the number of measurements.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation... I understood part of it, but did not understand the phrase "signal-to-noise ratio of the flux in the Gaussian." Flux refers to the number of photons? Given a value for flux, what determines its SNR?

Comment: @AnnaNaden The *minimum* level of noise would be the square root of the number of detected photons. In practice, there are other contributing noise sources.

Comment: So, how is SNR calculated when analyzing a spectrograph (excluding other contributing noise sources for now)? Is it numerically equal to the square root of the number of photons detected?

Comment: Or the square root of the number of spectral lines analyzed?

Comment: Ignoring all other noise sources, the signal-to-noise ratio would be the square root of the number of detected photons. @AnnaNaden

Comment: well what about other noise sources, like thermal broadening of spectral lines? How would that affect the SNR?

Comment: @AnnaNaden thermal broadening isn't noise. If the spectrograph has a high enough resolving power then it means that the observed line widths will become broader and the precision will become lower because of that.

Comment: The reason I asked about thermal is I want to understand how a 1 m/s movement of a star can be detected in the presence of the much much higher thermal velocity of the atoms of the star's surface

Comment: @AnnaNaden for most stars, like the Sun, the "thermal broadening" is less than the instrumental broadening (which is what you asked about).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135318/discussion-between-anna-naden-and-profrob).

Answer (score 2):

Resolution tells you how well the spectrometer can separate lines with wavelengths close together, but not how precisely it can measure the wavelength of a single line. Measurement precision can be much better than the resolution. Then, techniques like template correlation can effectively average measurements of many lines, improving precision even more.

Comment: I don't understand how precision can be better than resolution. That is my difficulty. If I know each of two lines precisely, shouldn't that enable me to resolve them?

Comment: @AnnaNaden If you have a collection of photons that come from a single line, each with its own measured wavelength, you may average the measured wavelengths to obtain a more precise measurement. If you average a million photons, the precision will, in principle, be 1/1000 of the resolution.

Comment: In the case of spectrographs, to go from resolving power of 200k to precision of one meter per second, it seems you would have to average "n" spectrographs where n is sqrt of 1500. (C/200k) Perhaps that's practical.

Comment: @AnnaNaden You don't need to average spectrographs. Each photon detected by a single spectrograph constitutes a measurement.

Comment: I'm curious about the averaging process. Does one merely average the frequencies of *all* the scattered photons (all angles) in a single spectrograph? I assume there's *some* kind of averaging going on

Comment: Or average the scattering angles of all photons?

Comment: @edv how did you determine the resolving power of your homemade spectrograph?

Comment: @Edv, I do not understand the post in Sandbox III, sorry. Can you provide a sentence or two of explanation? Did you measure the resolving power or calculate it from theory?

Comment: It is measured: the photo of the D lines is simply cropped from the 6000 pixel by 4000 pixel original echellogram photograph and the small cropped portion rotated for convenience, so the D lines are presented “ horizontally”. Then the image is processed with the ImageJ software: every pixel has an 8 bit grayscale value, from 0 to 255, so these intensities are plotted and curve fitting to Gaussians is performed. (A crude way to do the estimate is to use Photoshop to expand the image and count pixels to get the full width at half maximum heights of the two D lines.) Ask more, if you please!

Comment: OK, thanks that is clear

Comment: @edv were you able to relate your measured resolving power to the geometry of your device?

Comment: As I have built my spectrograph, I have found this paper to be very helpful: S.V. Bykov, B. Sharma, S.A. Asher, “High-Throughput, High-Resolution Echelle Deep-UV Raman Spectrometer”, Applied Spectroscopy, 67(8), 2013, 873-883. The theoretical resolving power eqpression, their equation 2, is R = 2W sin(theta)/lambda, where W is grating width, theta is blaze angle (Littrow config.) For their build, they calculate 1.6 million at 229 nm. For my spectrograph, theta is 75 degrees, W is 25 mm, and lambda is 589.3 nm, so R is just below 82,000. So my spectrograph is *far below* the theoretical limit.